# "Not X so much as Y" vs. "not so much X as Y"

Tags: grammaticality, idioms, negation, not-so-much-as

E.g.

> - which don't *describe an action* so much as *describe a state of being*
> - which don't so much *describe an action* as *describe a state of being*

Are both constructions grammatically correct? I have no clue.

Comment: This site isn't a substitute for a good grammar book, an English class, or even a conversation with a native speaker of English. Please show us that you have tried to use resources like these before asking the question.

Comment: Point out any grammar book that catalogs the different varieties of _so/as much .. as .._ construction. What kind of research is there to do?

Comment: Certainly not a horrible question. But certainly the most horrible title ever.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, but "describe a" becomes redundant in the second part of the phrase (in both) because you've already stated that the verb is describing, regardless of whether it's an action or a state of being.

It would be better written as "which don't so much describe an action as a state of being", etc.